# AutoFS not working as expected with CIFS shares

Tags: centos, mount, windows, cifs, autofs

I have this setup

> **Client:** Centos 7.6.1810 up to date
>
> **Server:** Windows 7 pro

**AutoFS Configuration**

```
# tail -1 /etc/auto.master
/srv/xray   /etc/auto.xray

# cat /etc/auto.xray
cdm8240  -fstype=cifs,ro,vers=2.0,credentials=/etc/auto.smb.cdm8-240.credentials  ://my.server/share/

# cat /etc/auto.smb.cdm8-240.credentials
username=mylogin
password=passpass123
```

if I mount this share manually, everything is fine

```
# mount.cifs -o ro,vers=2.0,credentials=/etc/auto.smb.cdm8-240.credentials //my.server/share/ /srv/xray/

# ls -l /srv/xray/ | wc -l
34
# umount /srv/xray/
```

If I try with autofs, I have this wrong mount entry.

```
/etc/auto.xray on /srv/xray type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=17,pgrp=71348,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect,pipe_ino=404555)
```

Then I tried to pre-create the mount point `cdm8240` in the /srv/xray/ folder...

```
# ls -ld /srv/xray/cdm8240/
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 6 Jun  6 08:17 /srv/xray/cdm8240/
```

...reload autofs and access the share and it works

```
# systemctl restart autofs
# ls -l /srv/xray/cdm8240/ | wc -l
34
```

But now here is the weird part, if I restart autofs, it dismounts the share and remove the cdm8240 folder!

```
# systemctl restart autofs
# find /srv/xray/ -ls
406293    0 drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root            0 Jun  6 08:20 /srv/xray/
```

And even changing the perms on /srv/xray/, leaving it with 755 instead of the 777 it has before! And I come back to the first situation and it's wrong mount entry.

**Update 1**

Tried with the "direct" mode and it looks fine now

```
# tail -1 /etc/auto.master
/-   /etc/auto.xray

# cat /etc/auto.xray 
/test/cdm8240  -fstype=cifs,ro,credentials=/etc/.cdm8240cred,vers=2.1,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,users  ://my.server/share
```

so, is it a bug in the indirect mode or something "normal"?

**Update 2**
As explained bellow, everything was fine. I added `--ghost` option in my auto.master file as follow

```
/srv/autofs/xray   /etc/auto.xray --ghost
```

now the share is displayed and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

That looks perfectly normal.

The automounter takes over the top level directory, `/srv/xray` for all the mounts defined in the corresponding file or program, `/etc/auto.xray`. (In your case it's a normal file.)

Filesystems are only mounted on demand, so when you looked inside `/srv/xray` you would initially have seen nothing. But when you ran `ls -ld /srv/xray/cdm8240/` the automounter saw the reference to the mapped directory `cmd8240` and mounted the corresponding filesystem at `/srv/xray/cdm8240` for you.

At some point in the future, once you'd stopped accessing the filesystem mounted at `/srv/xray/cdm8240` the automounter would unmount it and `/srv/xray` would appear to be empty once more.

---

What I personally find helpful is to run the automounter underneath `/var/autofs`, so that for a mapping file `auto.misc` I'd have `/var/autofs/misc` and for an entry `remote` in that `auto.misc` file I'd have `/var/autofs/misc/remote`.

I then create a top-level directory `/autofs` and symlink directories from `/var/autofs/misc/`. This way they're visible to me even when not mounted, and I never need to worry about the `/var/autofs/misc` directory tree again.

```
mkdir -p -m755 /autofs
cd /autofs
ln -s ../var/autofs/misc/remote    # Create link to automounted 'remote'
```